# Application Error (file:///android_asset/www/index.html)

Tags: android

I have created an Android app that has the purpose to promote my country all over the world., using Intel XDk ( using HTML 5 and JavaScript ). You can download the app from here [1](https://www.dropbox.com/s/kdelil1ddocd8ub/Discover%20Romania%20.apk?dl=0)

Every time I start the app with the device connected to the internet, it says 
Application Error The connection to the server was unsuccessful (file:///android_asset/www/index.html), but when I turn off the Internet it works. Some features require Internet connection, so I really need to connect the device to internet.
The only on-line plugin that I use is a speech to text plugin downloaded from here [2](https://github.com/poiuytrez/SpeechRecognizer). Can somebody help me solve this problem? 
                                                     Alex Hang

Comment: please provide line of code where you are trying to connect to server

Comment: `function onDeviceReady(){
                console.log("Device is ready");
            }

            function recognizeSpeech() {
                var maxMatches = 1;
                var promptString = "Speak now"; 
                var language = "en-US";                    
                window.plugins.speechrecognizer.startRecognize(function(result) `

Answer (score 1):

```
file:///android_asset/www/index.html
```

Is a pointer to the local assets directory within the package of your application. Instead of trying to connect to is just use loadDataWithBaseURL and then point it to your assets. The issue with this is that it is a local copy of the html page, so it changes occur you have to update the file in the assets directory.

```
 WebView article = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.article_webview);
 article.loadDataWithBaseURL("file:///android_asset/www/index.html", null, "text/html", "UTF-8", null );
```

Comment: Where should I put that code ?  WebView article = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.article_webview);
 article.loadDataWithBaseURL("file:///android_asset/www/index.html", null, "text/html", "UTF-8", null );    In the index.html file? Thank you !